# fusioninventory, ITSM

Tags: inventory-management

to begin with, I have an internship with a trading company that has 15 points of sale. My mission is to manage its IT infrastructure with ITSM  9.1.6.
To discover its network, I use Fusioninventory 9.1+1.0. 
I also have installed the latest Fusioninventory agent for Windows. My problem is that I only get response from only 10 points of sale. I didn't get my problem to solve it because the agent works well (for the 15 points of sale).

PS: it's not a problem of a firewall, I installed the netdiscovery, deploy, ESX and the other fusioninventory features

I don't have a good knowledge about ITSM neither about the Fusioninventory but I followed tutorials.

Soryy if I asked dummy questions but could any one help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

You should check the logs to start debugging.

1. Enable logging by seting debug to 1 or 2. Open regedit and head to `HKLM/Software/Fusioninventory/` find the debug key and edit it.
2. If you are running the agent as a service then restart it, otherwise just execute the fusioninventory-agent.bat script to launch a new inventory.
3. Check the logs. They are usually at `%programfiles%\fusioninventory-agent\` although I think they are better at `%programfiles%\fusioninventory-agent\var\`. You can change where to store the log at the logfile key.

There you'll find what is stopping your inventory from reaching the server.